# show that the following complex function is entire (Laurent series/Taylor series)

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have the function $f(z) = \frac{\cos z - 1}{z^2}$ for $z \neq 0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ for $z = 0$.  I want to show that the function is entire.  First of all, I know that it has a Taylor expansion, since the singularity at $z = 0$ is removable.  The Taylor series about $z = 0$ is $-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4!} - \frac{z^4}{6!} + ...$

All that remains to show is that the radius of convergence for this series is $\infty$, which I am not sure how to show.

Comment: it is obvious that the radius of convergence is the same as $\cos(z)$ (or $\cos(z)-1$ it is the same). in general if $f(z)$'s Taylor series around $z=0$ has a radius of convergence $R$, then $\frac{f(z)}{z^k}$'s ***Laurent*** series around $z=0$ has a radius of convergence $R$, and it is enough to show there are no negative terms (i.e. that it is holomorphic/analytic at $z=0$) for showing it is holomorphic/analytic on $|z| < R$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\ldots \tag{1}$$
$$\cos(z)-1=-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\ldots \tag{2}$$
$$\frac{\cos(z)-1}{z^2}=-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{4!}-\ldots \tag{3}$$

The radius of convergence of $(1)$ is $+\infty$, and the operations we made in $(1)\mapsto(2)$ and $(2)\mapsto (3)$ do not alter the radius of convergence. Since the cosine function is an entire function, so it is $\frac{\cos(z)-1}{z^2}$. Another possible approach: $\text{sinc}(z)$ is an entire function, so it is $\text{sinc}(z)^2$, so it is $\text{sinc}(z/2)^2$, so it is our function.

At last, the overkill.
$$\text{sinc}(z)=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)\tag{4} $$
implies:
$$ \frac{\cos z-1}{z^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{4n^2 \pi^2}\right)^2.\tag{5}$$

Comment: remark : showing $f(z)^2$'s Taylor series has (at least) the same ROC as $f(z)$ is not so obvious, I would use the Cauchy integral formula (reducing the ROC to the distance to the nearest singularity) for that

Comment: @user1952009: I would use another approach (Cauchy's approach): $$[z^n]f(z)^2 = \sum_{m=0}^{n}[z^m]f(z)\cdot [z^{n-m}]f(z), $$ so assuming that $[z^m]f(z)$ is bounded in absolute value by $K^m$, $[z^n]f(z)^2$ is bounded in absolute value by $n K^n$, so the radius of convergence of $f(z)^2$ is at least equal to the radius of convergence of $f(z)$, since $\lim_{n\to +\infty}n^{1/n}=1$. No singularities directly involved.

Comment: yes I saw that after, that $(\sum_n a_n z^n )^2 = \sum_n c_n z^n$ the order of $c_n$ has say the same order as $ n a_n$